# Lamdba expression Python to square even numbers and cube odd numbers

Tags: python, lambda

I am using Python 3.8 and I am attempting to write a lambda expression to square even numbers and cube odd numbers. So far, the code I have come for is as follows:

```
l = list(range(1, 11))

list(filter(lambda x: x ** 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3, l))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

The syntax for if, else using lambda is:

```
lambda <arguments> : <Return Value if condition is True> if <condition> else <Return Value if condition is False>
```

However, the lambda expression is not doing the job. Help?

Comment: The problem is not your `lambda`. You are using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) which does: *"Construct an iterator from those elements of iterable __for which function returns true__."*. Since all the results of this `lambda` are *truthy* (different than 0), you simply get all the ***original*** elements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda is correct, but you need to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the function to the elements of the list, not [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) it.

```py
l = list(range(1, 11))

list(map(lambda x: x ** 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3, l))
# [1, 4, 27, 16, 125, 36, 343, 64, 729, 100]
```

---

Another more pythonic way is through list comprehension

```py
f = lambda x: x ** 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3
[f(x) for x in l]
```

Or even better without the lambda expression:

```py
[x ** 2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3 for x in l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa map

```
number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
new = list(map(lambda x: x**2 if x % 2 == 0 else x ** 3, number))
```

out

```
new = [1, 4, 27, 16, 125, 36]
```